# insert list<text> cassandra using java

Tags: java, list, cassandra, cql

I"m trying to insert a list in cassandra, but I getting this error:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Invalid
>   amount of bind variables

The table in cassandra is:

```
CREATE TABLE list (name text PRIMARY KEY, values list<text> );
```

My query using java is:

```
public void insert(String name, List<String> values) {
    execute("INSERT INTO list (name, values) VALUES ('%s', ?)", name, values);
    }
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are providing more bind variables than you have in the query. The following should work:

```
public void insert(String name, List<String> values) {
    execute("INSERT INTO list (name, values) VALUES (?, ?)", name, values);
}
```

Comment: Nothing change with this, i have allways the same error! The only two variables that i'm providing are name and values and this should be correct!!

Comment: @andrea Look at the code in this answer vs your post.  You should use two ?'s, instead of a %s and one ?.

Comment: I tried with the two ? but it doesn't work

Comment: Nobody can help me??